# Script to move an entire row to from a Google form responses sheet to another sheet based on cell value

Tags: forms, google-sheets

I'm trying to use the following code to move an entire row from a Google form responses sheet to another sheet based on a cell value, however for some reason it won't work. If I run it on another sheet, it works perfectly fine. Any recommendations?

````
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
 var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

 if(s.getName() == "Jobs" && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "Complete") {
   var row = r.getRow();
   var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
   var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
   s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
   s.deleteRow(row);
 }
}```
````

Comment: you can only have one function named onEdit() in any given spreadsheet.  Any chance that's the issue you're having?

Answer (score 0):

### When running triggers, the active sheet often defaults to the first sheet of the spreadsheet

Solution:

Instead of defining

```
 var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
 var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
```

use the event object `range`:

```
 var r = event.range;
 var s = r.getSheet();
```

Also, your `if` condition is
`if(s.getName() == "Jobs"...)`. So obviously you will only enter the `if` code block for the sheet that is actually called `"Jobs"` and not for the other sheets.